# wrong answer on mathematics when adding vectors

Tags: vector

can anyone know how to solve this simple problem:

```
{{3}, {0}, {3}, {0}} - Fout /. Fout -> {{0}, {0}, {1}, {1}}  

{{3}, {0}, {3}, {0}} - {{0}, {0}, {1}, {1}}
```

those must show the same result, but they dont!
i need simple element wise vector addition
do i do something wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Similar to the higher precedence of `*` over `+`, in the code you show the precedence of `-` is higher than the precedence of `/.` so it subtracts the symbol `Fout` from your vector first and then does the substitution.

Just as with `*` and `+`, you can change the behavior of precedence using `()` like this

```
{{3}, {0}, {3}, {0}} - (Fout /. Fout -> {{0}, {0}, {1}, {1}})
```

which results in `{{3}, {0}, {2}, {-1}}` because the `()` makes the substitution happen before the subtraction

Comment: (+1) It might be also worthwhile to mention that symbols are treated by default "as scalars" because`Plus` has the attribute "Listable".